What is bias and bias per group for simple linear regression and mixed models respectively?
I found this nice diagram on the Wikipedia mixed model page showing the difference between a simple linear regression and a linear mixed model, however I don't understand what they mean by bias and bias per group here.
I know that estimation of the mixed effects parameters is done by sampling a distribution with fixed variance and therefore we only lose 1 degrees of freedom. Why should there be a bias for every group/level in the mixed model?

Does this have something to do with BLUEs and BLUPs? Are they just talking about the intercept?

without the axis labels I can't quite tell, but the second plot looks to me like just fitting varying intercepts & slopes per group.  In this context I can't quite make sense why they'd call that 'bias' though

Bias in machine learning is sometimes used to refer to an 'offset' i.e. an intercept term (see this question for different usages of 'bias'). So all the figure means is that in the first panel, there is a single intercept, while in the second, each group has a separate intercept.
I don't think it's a particularly illuminating figure, though - the third panel in particular is rather unclear and doesn't quite communicate what a mixed model does.

Thanks for the answer. I think so too.
As for the third panel, this is how I interpreted it and please let me know if I'm wrong:
A variance parameter is derived from the covariance structure of the data and the random effect coefficients are derived from sampling a normal distribution with that variance. This in turn has the effect of 'repositioning' the points to correct for the correlated residuals. So in the last panel, what they are showing is that if we extract the random effect line for each group with the points for that group and then superimpose those lines, we get panel 3.

@Cats I wouldn't really bother to try to interpret an unclear visual aid. If you're interested in understanding mixed models, there's plenty of better text- and maths-based explanations (including on this site).
